# Image disappears when set borderRadious

Tags: react-native, expo

When I set borderRadious for an Image Component, the image disappears and the whole image is colored black. And Expo reboots automatically soon after. I was able to get around the error by making a wrap View for the image. The source is like below:

```
<View style={styles.avatarWrap}>
    <Image
        source={require('../../assets/flags/profileImage.png')}
        style={styles.avatar}
    />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  avatarWrap: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 100,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  avatar: {
    flex: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
```

It works, but I have no idea why it does not work when I apply borderRadious directly to an Image component. It has to have a wrap View component to not make an error. I tried to use `<Image borderRaious='100'/>` not on the style. It did not work. Is it a bug?

Comment: Have you tried by adding inline style
<Image
        source={require('../../assets/flags/profileImage.png')}
        style={{[styles.avatar], borderRadius:100}}
    />

Comment: That's a very large `borderRadius` so, depending on the size of the image, it's not surprising that you might not see anything.  Try setting it to 10.  Also `borderRadius` is not supported directly on the Image object, just the style, e.g., `<Image style={{borderRadius:10}} source={...`

Comment: @Pramod I have tried that one but it did not work :(

Comment: @MikeM Oh, was it related to the size of borderRadious? Actually, when I tried borderRadious: 20, the images showed up, but when the number of images were more than 7, they all suddenly disappeared and turned to black.